# How to change a video based on the time another video is paused at in HTML

Tags: html

I'm trying to figure out how I would switch to another video if the current video is paused within a specific range (Ex. pausing the video between 2-4 secs will change the video)

I'm assuming I have to implement the played property in some way here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to know the played ranges to know when the video was paused.  Use `currentTime`, and check it when the `pause` event fires:

```
vid.addEventListener('pause', (e) => {
  if (e.currentTarget.currentTime > 2 && e.currentTarget.currentTime < 4) {
    vid.src = 'something-else.mkv';
  }
});
```

Comment: No problem.  If you found this answer helpful, you can accept it as the answer to your question by clicking the checkmark next to it.  That way, future readers with similar problems will be able to find the solution quickly.